# Query using pivot?

Tags: plsql

I have the following data

```
WITH    got_grp   AS
(
 SELECT  '1111' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '0'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1111' AS LINE_NBR, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '0'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1112' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '1'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1113' AS LINE_NBR, '122' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '12'   AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1114' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '14.4' AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1116' AS LINE_NBR, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '11'   AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
)
```

I would like to retrieve the totals for a specific I_N for a AMOUNT_ID.
I want the query to return values if exist row for all the amounts_id (121,122,522) and if the total of
the amounts is larger than 30 (AMOUNT_ID_121   +  AMOUNT_ID_122   + AMOUNT_ID_522 > 30)

For example :

I_N  | AMOUNT_ID_121   |  AMOUNT_ID_122  |    AMOUNT_ID_522

A    |    11           |        12      |      15.4

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Use `SUM` aggregate function in your `PIVOT` clause for particular `AMOUNT_ID` values (121,122,522). Then you can `SUM` the amounts and `GROUP BY` your `I_N` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH got_grp   AS
(
 SELECT  '1111' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '0'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1111' AS LINE_NBR, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '0'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1112' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '1'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1113' AS LINE_NBR, '122' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '12'   AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1114' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '14,4' AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1116' AS LINE_NBR, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '11'   AS AMOUNT    FROM dual
)
select LINE_NBR, I_N, AMOUNT_ID_522, AMOUNT_ID_121, AMOUNT_ID_122
from(
select LINE_NBR, AMOUNT_ID, I_N, AMOUNT
FROM got_grp)
PIVOT(SUM(AMOUNT) FOR AMOUNT_ID IN ('522' AS AMOUNT_ID_522, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID_121, '122' AS AMOUNT_ID_122)
)
WHERE
 NVL(AMOUNT_ID_522,0)+NVL(AMOUNT_ID_121,0)+NVL(AMOUNT_ID_122,0)>30;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH got_grp   AS
(
 SELECT  '1111' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '0'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1111' AS LINE_NBR, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '0'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1112' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '1'    AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1113' AS LINE_NBR, '122' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '12'   AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1114' AS LINE_NBR, '522' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '14.4' AS AMOUNT    FROM dual  UNION ALL
 SELECT  '1116' AS LINE_NBR, '121' AS AMOUNT_ID, 'A' AS I_N,  '11'   AS AMOUNT    FROM dual
)
select *
  from got_grp PIVOT(SUM(AMOUNT) FOR AMOUNT_ID IN('522' AS AMOUNT_ID_522,
                                              '121' AS AMOUNT_ID_121,
                                              '122' AS AMOUNT_ID_122))
 WHERE AMOUNT_ID_522 IS NOT NULL
   AND AMOUNT_ID_121 IS NOT NULL
   AND AMOUNT_ID_122 IS NOT NULL
   AND AMOUNT_ID_522 + AMOUNT_ID_121 + AMOUNT_ID_122 > 30;
```